# Tail one logfile in multiple windows based on regex

Tags: logs

I have a single logfile that contains logs for a threaded application. Each thread writes its own name onto the lines they emit:

```
16.04.2021 10:10:04 - Thread-1 - DEBUG - I did something
16.04.2021 10:10:04 - Thread-2 - DEBUG - I too did something
16.04.2021 10:10:04 - Thread-3 - DEBUG - I failed :/
```

I'd like to follow/tail this logfile but each window/terminal should view only one thread so that I can more easily see what each thread is currently doing. I am using window/terminal loosely here: If I have 5 threads it should create 5 "windows" in the same terminal, each window showing one thread.

I have found many solutions (like `multitail`) that tail multiple logfiles but so far I have been unsuccessful in finding one that does what I described.

Comment: You could use `tmux` or `screen` to create 5 panes, and run a different command in each of them

Comment: It'd be nice if there was a single-command solution so that I don't have to open and arrange tmux windows every time I need this.

Comment: Use `tmux -f` to specify an alternate config file, and set up your panes and commands in there